# Sql BIDS aggregrate transform

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, bids

I have a question about the BIDS aggregrate transform. My data flow task begins with an Excel source, goes through an aggregate transform, and then into an OLE Database. I aggregrate my data by a project_id.

However, when I aggregate by the project_id I no longer have the information to the other fields. I want to keep the project_name field. How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that if your project_id and project_name fields in the Excel source have a 1:1 correspondence, then you could just add project_name as an additional input column with group by operation in the aggregrate transform.

Otherwise, you would need some sort of "official" mapping for project_name to project_id, which you could maybe store in a database and use a lookup transform to add the project_name column to the data flow.

Comment: Your first idea does not work, I have a huge dataset. Your second idea sounds like I would just be complicating my task.